# Lenovo T61p Windows 7 LCD Change Brightness Does Not Work

Tags: windows-7, drivers, thinkpad, lcd

Just installed Windows 7 on my T61p laptop.

Besides the fact that i only missed 2 drivers (turbo memory, wusb) there are plenty of things not working on windows drivers alone.

Main issue at the moment is that I can't change LCD brightness. When I use function keys I see slider moving in windows but no change on LCD.

Anyone had similar issues?

I would rather not install every 30mb lenovo bloatware they have on their site - for me driver is a 500B .inf file and not 30MB app with fancy graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got this issue fixed with a bunch updates from Windows Update.

I ASSUME it was the NVidia Quadro FX 570M drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on an X61 with Win 7 RC - Lenovo has not released an updated support package that enables the Fn keys on Win 7 yet (though I'm sure it'll be out by Oct 22nd).

Good (possibly better workaround) - Win+X to bring up Mobility Center, and then adjust the brightness slider.

Comment: my issue is that fn key works - it slides the slider, it just does nothing to my lcd's brightness

Comment: Hmm that's weird - have you tried updated drivers yet?

Also, due to the nature of graphics card driver, a simple .inf will not be suffice. No doubt I agree with you on cutting out the fluff, but you should try to install the Lenovo drivers and just disable the overheads of the driver software later.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue randomly on my Compaq Presario 15.6-inch notebook (CQ60-419WM).

- Sometimes FN ^ v keys do not change brightness
- Sometimes brightness slider is missing (!) from brightness/power options

I have found that rebooting/sleeping/hibernating will all fix it.

Answer (score 0):

My HP Compaq nw8440 disables brightness setting after wake up. When I press Fn+9 and Fn+f10 icons shows but the gauge bar and the brightness doesn't change. Reboot solves it. I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well, it occurs after hibernating or sleeping. I noticed that on certain occasions this can be resolved by unplugging the power source and plugging it back.

After you hear the beep that notifies the switch of the power source - the brightness controls are functional again.

It does not always work, unfortunately. When it does not, there is no *brightness control* in the Mobility Center window (Win+X ) at all. A reboot fixes that, but as someone who reboots infrequently - I'd love to use a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo N585 Win10- right click AMD Catalyst icon on taskbar, left click control center - select desktop management drop-down, select desktop color, adjust brightness. My temporary solution.

Answer (score -1):

On T61 Lenovo use the FN key and Home (brightness up) or End (brightness down). Home and End are in the upper right corner of keyboard and have dual markings. Second marking in blue shows brightness up or down icon.